# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow' on Kentico 13 Core

Tags: kentico

Following this tutorial to setup **Kentico Core 13** on local machine with New site as explained in article. It completed successfully. Post that created the Page types and when try to add pages using those page type use to get below error:
An error occurred while attempting to retrieve page templates. The live site application is not running or is not accessible.

When checked in developer console it states that :
GetResource.ashx?scriptmodule=/CMS/VirtualContextAuthenticator.js:1 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost:25291') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

Then I tried accessing live site and it is not working.
Hmmm… can't reach this page localhost refused to connect.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Sites application in Kentico, edit your site (click the pencil icon), and enter http://localhost:25291/ (or whatever your IIS Express default address is) into the *Presentation URL:* field. Save. See if it helps.